# Regex (gskinner) to extract words from a sentence

Tags: regex

I have a string, Hello~Tim~call-me-when-you-are-back-at~+339280908998

There are multiple fields in the existing message. `Greeting=Hello`, `Name=Tim`, `message=call-me-when-you-are-back-at`, `Phone=+339280908998`.

i.e, Basically first word before occurrence of `~` is `Greeting`, and between first and second occurrence of `~` is `Name`, between third and fourth occurrence of `~` is message and the last word after final occurrence of `~` is phone.

How do I extract these words.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, since there's only one occurence of  `~`?

Comment: The actual string looks something like this.

Hello~Tim~call-me-when-you-are-back-at~+339280908998

Comment: What programming language / framework.  Will you always have three tildes or does it vary?

Comment: It is Splunk's regular expression to extract fields from the message. And yes, this particular message always have tildes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it can be done, based on the string in your comment.

The regular expression you need is: `^([^~]*?)~([^~]*?)~([^~]*?)~(.*?)$`

Here's a link to the example: https://regex101.com/r/bW2cP7/2

Comment: Is there any way I can extract only particular set of field, Like, if there are 6 tildes and I want to extract content only between 3rd and 4th tildes?

Comment: Yes, it will only extract items with parentheses around them.